# Moment assumption for product of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let us say that $U$ is a random variable with finite second moments $E[U^2] < \infty$. Is there a moment condition on $T$, say $E|T|^k < \infty$ for some $k$, that guarantees $TU$ having finite second moment, i.e. $E[T^2 U^2] < \infty$? For example, if $T$ is bounded almost surely, this is true.

Comment: Without further assumptions on $U$, boundedness of $T$ is the best moment condition we can expect.

Comment: Can you give a counterexample or some sort of negative proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further assumptions on $U$, boundedness of $T$ is the best moment condition we can expect. As the following example shows, it is possible to construct $U \in L^2$ in such a way that for any $p \geq 1$ there exists $T \in L^p$ with $TU \notin L^2$ :

**Example:** Consider the probability space $[0,\tfrac{1}{2}]$ endowed with twice the Lebesgue measure and set $$U(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{\log x}.$$ Then $U \in L^2$. For fixed $p \geq 1$, define $$T(x) := \frac1{x^{\frac{1}{2p}}}.$$ Obviously, $T \in L^p$, but the identity $$(T^2U^2)(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1+\frac1{p}}} \frac{1}{(\log x)^2}$$ shows that $TU$ is not square integrable.